# How can I change colors on razer chroma items and save it on xbox?

Tags: xbox-one, keyboard, mouse, razer-synapse

I have been trying to change the color on my razer items, using razer synapse, but when I connect it to my xbox, it changes back.

How can I keep my changed colors?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you would like to do is device dependent, meaning even if you set the color scheme on the PC it will reset on xbox, because the setting is not saved on the controller, just on the PC.
Because of this, setting the color, I guess, could be possible with an **app** from the Microsoft store: **Razer Synapse for Xbox**, although that is for Razer Wolverine, maybe it will work with yours too. The razer synapse software, that you use on your pc is for windows only. The app from the store though should do the thing.
I never used razer products, but have an illuminated keyboard, that has a separate button for setting the light. In which case, the settings are actually stored on the controller, keyboard, etc.. Maybe check if such a button exists on your razer items?

Comment: yes i have tried razer synapse for xbox, and the app wont operate unless you have the wolverine razer controller.

Comment: I see, than the only thing I can think of, as google results are no help sadly, is trying to contact the Razer support, maybe they will be of more help.